# Prove that if $\text{adh}(A)=\text{adh}(B)$ then $d_{A}=d_{B}$

Tags: normed-spaces

I wanted to ask for some advice to show that $d_{A} = d_{B}$ assuming that $\text{adh}(A) = \text{adh}(B)$, where $d_{X}(x):=\inf_{y\in X}|| x-y||$, is the distance function.

Comment: You could perhaps prove that $d_A = d_{\text{adh}(A)}$.